# Add a common route for multiple resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I add the `/search` endpoint to all these resources in one go?

```
MyCoolApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts, only [:index, :show, :create] do
    collection { get :search }
  end

  resources :authors, only [:index, :show] do
    collection { get :search }
  end

  resources :comments, only: [:index, :show] do
    collection { get :search }
  end

  resources :categories, only: [:index, :show] do
    collection { get :search }
  end

  resources :tags, only: [:index] do
    collection { get :search }
  end
end
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5247045/986415) which is close, but I need to be able to specify the actions for reach resource. Is there a better way to inject the search route in a better way?

```
%w(one two three four etc).each do |r|
  resources r do
    collection do
      post 'common_action'
    end
  end
end
```

Something like this?

```
resources :posts, only [:index, :show, :create, :search]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you've tagged this question `ruby-on-rails-3`, but I'm going to provide the Rails 4 solution for anyone who comes across this in the future.

Rails 4 introduces **[Routing Concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns)**

```
concern :searchable do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end

resources :posts, only [:index, :show, :create], concerns: [:searchable]
resources :authors, only [:index, :show], concerns: [:searchable]
resources :comments, only: [:index, :show], concerns: [:searchable]
resources :categories, only: [:index, :show], concerns: [:searchable]
resources :tags, only: [:index], concerns: [:searchable]
```

Comment: ah very nice. As it turns out, we're actually using Rails 4, but I'm still in the habit of using it the same as Rails 3. Let me test and let you know.

Comment: Works great! Tests are green :) Thank you!